# wget command not found while dowloading file - R

Tags: r, wget

I am on Mac M1 running R 4.2.0 and using R-studio. My ultimate motivation is to download a package using *BiocManager* - following tips on https://support.bioconductor.org/p/19598/ ( I am getting the same error as that user was).

To do so, my impression is that I need to be able to download using `wget`. Now, in my R terminal, when I run `options("download.file.method"="wget")`, it returns no error. However, if I then do, `wget -V`, it says it isn't found. If I do `?wget`, even that returns `No documentation for ‘wget’ in specified packages and libraries`.

And when I run`BiocManager::install(c('BiocGenerics'))`,  this yields the following error,

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/experiment/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2:
  'wget' call had nonzero exit status
sh: wget: command not found
sh: wget: command not found
sh: wget: command not found
```

My question - how do I get `wget` to work on R?

**EDIT**: I do have wget functioning on my Mac's command line.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/YuLab-SMU/wget) help?

Comment: I downloaded it and did '''library(wget)''', and set wget to my download method. However, it still returns the same error. Any idea why?